# Couchdb 3.1.0 cluster - database failed to load after restarting one node

Tags: docker, couchdb

Here is the situation : on a couchdb cluster made of two nodes, each node is a couchdb docker instance on a server (ip1 and ip2). I had to reboot one server and restart docker, after that both my couchdb instances displays for each database: "This database failed to load."

I can connect with Futon and see the full list of databases, but that's all. On "Verify Couchdb Installation" with Futon I have several errors (only 'Create database' is a green check)

The docker logs for the container gives me this error :

```
"internal_server_error : No DB shards could be opened"
```

I tried to recover the database locally by copying the .couch and shards/ files to a local instance of couchdb but the same problem occurs.

How can I retrieve the data ?

PS: I checked the connectivity between my two nodes with `erl`, no problem there. Looks like docker messed up with some couchdb config file on restart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## metadata and cloning a node

The individual databases have [metadata](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/3.1.0/api/database/shard.html#db-shards) indicating on which nodes their shards are stored which is built on creation based on [cluster options](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/3.1.0/config/cluster.html#cluster-options), so copying database files alone does not actually move or mirror the database on to the new node. (If one sets the metadata correctly the shards are copied by couch itself, so [copying the files is only done to speed up the process](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/3.1.0/cluster/sharding.html#copying-shard-files).)

## replica count

A 2 node cluster usually does not make sense. As with file system RAID, you can stripe for maximal performance and half the reliability or you can create a mirror, but unless individual node state has perfect consistency detection one can not automatically decide which of two nodes is incorrect, while deciding which of 3 nodes is incorrect is easy enough to perform automatically. Consequently, most clusters are 3 or more nodes and each shard has 3 replicas on any 3 nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, just in case someone do the same mistake :

When you have a 2 node cluster, couchdb@ip1 and couchdb@ip2, and created the cluster from couchdb@ip1 :

1) If the node couchdb@ip2 stops, then the cluster setup is messed up (couchdb@ip1 will no longer work), on restart it appears that the node will not connect correctly and the databases will appear but will not be available.

2) On the other hand, stoping and starting couchdb@ip1 do not cause any problem

The solution in case 1 is to recreate the cluster with 2 fresh couchdb instances (couchdb@ip1 and couchdb@ip2), then copy the databases on one couchdb instance and all the databases will be back !

If anyone can explain in detail why this happend ? It also means that this cluster configuration is absolutly not reliable (if couchdb@ip2 is down then nothing works), I guess it will not be the same with a 3 nodes cluster ?